# How to connect android application to localhost?

Tags: java, python, android

I am building an a chat bot that should run on android, I've all the chat bot working correctly written in python in my machine, and I have the android app UI built, now I am looking to send the request entered by the user to the my machine in order to be processed and to send back the response, since I don't have long experience developing on android I can't find out how to send the request, or how to connect my android UI with the python code in my machine.

Comment: You need to use your device IP.

Comment: You should take a Socket and let it connect to the ip-address of 'my machine' using the right port. That for a start.

Comment: And of course if you want anyone else to use this, you should run your python server application (because that's what it is) on an actual server.